# Entity Framework Code First Update-Database does not take my Initializer code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My issue is that when I run my web app (and delete the DB) my database initializer works perfectly, however when I enter `Add-Migration Initial` & `Update-Database`, only the database is create without the initialization data !!

I have the following code:
(This is in PROJ1.EF Project)

```
public class StudentsContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        public StudentsContext ()
            : base("StudentsContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<StudentsContext>(new StudentsContextInitializer());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

The following is my `StudentsContextInitializer`:

```
public class StudentsContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<StudentsContext>
{
        protected override void Seed(StudentsContext context)
        {
            var students = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student("Alex ABC"),
                new Student("John Doe")
            };

            students.ForEach(s => context.Students.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            base.Seed(context);
        }
}
```

My `web.config` has the following entries in its `<entityFramework>` tag:
(This is in PROJ1.Web Project)

```
<contexts>
  <context type="PROJ1.EF.StudentContext, PROJ1.EF">
    <databaseInitializer type="PROJ1.EF.StudentsInitializer, PROJ1.EF" />
  </context>
</contexts>
```

Please help.

Comment: I think your `Database.SetInitializer<StudentsContext>` call is too late. Try putting it in a static constructor. i.e. `static StudentsContext() { /* set initializer */ }`

Comment: And for what it's worth, `<databaseInitializer type="PROJ1.EF.StudentsInitializer, PROJ1.EF" />` refers to `StudentsInitializer` but your class is called `StudentsContextInitializer`

Comment: And for what it's worth as well, what's the point of `Add-Migration Initial` and `Update-Database` for something that's based on `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<StudentsContext>`. Seems like migrations are mutually exclusive, here.

Comment: ta.speot.is in right. When you run Enable-Migrations a new class is added to your project; Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContext> and this is the one that has the Seed method that will be executed when you run the migrations (Update-Database).

Comment: Thanks ta.speot & Augusto ,, I think the main issue is that DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContext> creates new Seed method which is empty ,, how to integrate this with my Initializer class as I don't want to put the same code in this new Seed method (any new Add-Migration would create new Seed method right??)

Comment: @AMH No, it won't create a new Seed method. You'll only have one DbMigrationsConfiguration. You could create a separate class (ex: InitialSeed) and use it from all places, but if you are using migrations then there is no point in using DropCreateDatabaseAlways. You'll have to use MigrateToLatestVersion initializer. Please, read this article written by Arthur Vickers from the EF team: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/. It'll help you understand this situation ;).