# Update-Database not using custom initialzer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

**Please do not mistake [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28779668/1384204) SO question as a duplicate:**

I have the following config for a custom database initializer for code first entity framework:

```
<entityFramework>
  <contexts>
    <context type="MyApp.Context, MyApp">
      <databaseInitializer type="MyApp.CustomInitializer, MyApp" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
</entityFramework>
```

When I run the application all is well and the `InitializeDatabase(Context context)` method is called as expected.

However, when running the command `Update-Database` in the Package manager console it is not using my custom initializer.

Why does it work when running the app but not from the package manager console? Which initializer will it be using?

Comment: Is that config in the same project used for `Update-Database`, either as the default project in the console or selected by `-ProjectName` or `-StartUpProjectName`?

Comment: It is not in the same project where `Update-Database` is used. it is in the start up project. I assumed this config only existing in the start up project would suffice since the command takes the connection string from the start up...

Comment: I have now added the above config to the project containing the migrations but has made no difference. The migrations still run using a different initializer

Comment: What does `Update-Database` need the initializer for?

Comment: There's a `-ConfigurationTypeName` option if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @jjj I have customized my initialiser which performs additional maintenance after each migration.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `Update-Database` does not use a database initializer at all. It creates a `DbMigrator` to handle the update (which is also what the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer uses), and either tries to find a `DbMigrationsConfiguration` class or uses one that you provide on the command line.

If you need to do some maintenance after a migration, you can use the `Up()` function in the migration itself. Or I suppose you could the `Seed()` function in your class that overrides `DbMigrationsConfiguration` (but by default, `Seed()` runs for [*every*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822618/confusion-over-ef-auto-migrations-and-seeding-seeding-every-program-start) database initialization...however, [there are ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510341/entity-framework-5-migrations-setting-up-an-initial-migration-and-single-seed-o) to work around this.)

If you want to see it at work: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Migrations/Design/ToolingFacade.cs

Answer (score -1):

If you call Update-Database without specifying where is the ConfigurationType it is assumed that it is in the same assembly. An example :

```
Update-Database -ProjectName MyApp.Migrations -ConfigurationTypeName "MyApp.Migrations.MyMigrationConfiguration" -ConnectionString "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myAppDb;Trusted_Connection=False;User ID=xx;Password=xxxxxx" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: I think that command is used for when there are multiple configurations, whereas this question is about a custom 'Initializer'